# How to use refernce concept and access element of subroutine argument using Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am writing a code for calling a subroutine which has 4 argument(3 hashes and one file handler).i want to know how to access them in subroutine.My code is as below.

```
#print OUTFILE "Content of TPC file:.\n";
my $DATA_INFO = $ARGV[0];
my $OUT_DIR = $ARGV[1];
my $log= "$OUT_DIR/log1";
open(LOG1,">$log");
require "$DATA_INFO";
my $SCRIPT_DIR = $ENV{"SCRIPT_DIR"} ; 
require "$SCRIPT_DIR/cmp_fault.pl";
require "$SCRIPT_DIR/pattern_mismatch.pl";
require "$SCRIPT_DIR/scan_count.pl";

print "\nComparing data:\n\n" ;
pattern_mismatch("\%data","\%VAR1","\%status",*LOG1);
cmp_fault("\%data","\%VAR1","\%status",*LOG1);
scan_count("\%data","\%status",*LOG1);
print "\n Comparison done:\n";

foreach $pattern (keys %status) {
 print "pattern";
  foreach $attr (keys %{$status{$pattern}}) {
   print ",$attr";
 }
 print "\n";
 last; 
 }    

 #Print Data
 foreach $pattern (keys %status) {
  print "$pattern";
 foreach $attr (keys %{$status{$pattern}}) {
  print ",$status{$pattern}{$attr}";
```

}
    print "\n";

## Sub routine cmp_fault is here:

```
sub cmp_fault {
use strict;
use warning;
$data_ref= $_[0];;
$VAR1_ref= $_[1];
$status_ref = $_[2];
$log1_ref=$_[3];

 # print LOG1"For TPC : First find the pattern and then its fault type\n";

 for $pat ( keys %$data_ref ) {
  print  "fgh:\n$pat,";
  for $key (keys %{$data_ref{$pat}}) {
    if($key=~/fault/){
      print LOG1 "$key:$data_ref{$pat}{$key},\n";
       }
    }
}
 # print LOG1 "\nFor XLS : First find the pattern and then its pattern type\n";
  for $sheet (keys %$VAR1_ref){
   if ("$sheet" eq "ATPG") {
     for $row (1 .. $#{$VAR1_ref->{$sheet}}) {
       $patname = $VAR1_ref->{'ATPG'}[$row]{'Pattern'} ;
         next if ("$patname" eq "") ;
          $faultXls  = $VAR1_ref->{'ATPG'}[$row]{'FaultType'} ;
    #         print LOG1 " $patname==>$faultXls \n";
      if (defined $data{$patname}{'fault'}) {
      $faultTpc = $data{$patname}{'fault'} ;
     #     print LOG1 "\n $patname :XLS: $faultXls :TPC: $faultTpc\n";
          if("$faultXls" eq "$faultTpc") { 
           print LOG1 "PASS: FaultType Matched $patname :XLS: $faultXls :TPC: $faultTpc\n\n\n";
         print  "PASS: FaultType Matched $patname :XLS: $faultXls :TPC: $faultTpc\n\n";
         $status_ref->{$patname}{'FaultType'} = PASS;

        } 
       else {
          print LOG1 "FAIL: FaultType Doesn't Match\n\n";
       $status_ref->{$patname}{'FaultType'} = Fail;   
            }
       }
    }        
   }
  }
}
 return 1;
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Ohk thankkxx for replying....i vl use it.But how to access that 3 hash into sub routine

Comment: That's not the biggest problem with your code, which frankly is a bit of a mess. You're accessing variables that aren't defined/in scope. `strict` and `warnings` would tell you about these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing parameters into an array, you can only ever pass a single list of parameters.

For scalars, this isn't a problem. If all you're acting on is a single array, this also isn't a problem.

If you need to send scalars and an array or hash, then the easy way is to 'extract' the scalar parameters first, and then treat 'everything else' as the list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub scalars_and_array {
    my ( $first, $second, @rest ) = @_;
    print "$first, $second, ", join( ":", @rest ), "\n";
}

scalars_and_array( "1", "2", "3", 4, 5, 6 );
```

But it should be noted that by doing so - you're passing *values*. You can do this with hashes too.

To pass data structure references, it's as you note - pass by reference, then dereference. It's useful to be aware though, that `->` becomes useful, because it's accessing a hash *and* dereferencing it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub pass_hash {
    my ( $hashref ) = @_;
    print $hashref,"\n";
    print $hashref -> {"one"},"\n";
    print $hashref -> {"fish"} -> {"haddock"};
}


my %test_hash = ( "one" => 2,
                  "three" => 4, 
                  "fish" => { "haddock" => "plaice" }, );

pass_hash ( \%test_hash ); 
print "\n";
print Dumper \%test_hash;
```

The core of your problem here though, is that you haven't turned on `strict` and `warnings` which would tell you that:

```
for $pat ( keys %data_ref ) {
```

is wrong - there is no hash called `data_ref` there's only a scalar (which holds a hash reference) called `$data_ref`.

You need `%$data_ref` here.

And here:

```
for $key ( keys %{ $data{$pat} } ) {
```

You also have no `$data` - your code says `$data_ref`. (You might have `%data` in scope, but that's a really bad idea to mess around with within a sub).

There's a bunch of other errors - which would also be revealed by `strict` and `warnings`. That's a very basic debugging step, and you will generally get a much better response from Stack Overflow if you do this before asking for assistance. So please - do that, tidy up your code and remove errors/warnings. If you are still having problems after that, then by all means make a post outlining where and what problem you're having.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.I got very good tips but after replcing $data_ref to %$data_ref , now that sub routine is not at all working.Can u pls throw some light on Variable "$VAR1" is not imported at /project/ls1socdft/user/pooja/test_plan_checker/dfta/perl/pattern_qa/script/cmp_fault.pl line 23.other errors.I am getting warning like this "

Comment: That error means - you're using `$VAR1` when it's not defined. Which is true. Because you have `$VAR_ref`, and NO `$VAR1` within your sub. Perl does not magically translate between the two. Which in turn means - you should be turning on `strict` and `warnings` and fixing the errors in your code, because they are almost certainly why you are having problems.

Comment: now i have activated strict,warning and changed that var1 to the var1_ref.But stil problem.

Comment: OK. If you are still having problems, please repost your new code and highlight where you're having difficulties.

Comment: Nope. Turn on `strict` and `warnings`. Fix those first.

Comment: When I say 'turn on strict and warnings' I mean "and then run the code, and fix the errors you get".

Comment: Problem solved..Dat was issue of string ,double quotes.